# 2nd order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on the following 2nd order ODE:
$$
x^2 y''+2(2x-1/b^2) y'+2(1-(a/b)^2)y=0,
$$
where $b\neq 0$. It's very similar to the equation for the generalized Bessel polynomials (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_polynomials ); There's a slight difference in the factor in front of $y$ though. Any advise on how to handle the beast? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Little update: in the special case when $a=0$ the solution is rather simple---it's the Frechet distribution $y=[2/(bx)^2]e^{-2/(b^2x)}$, where $x>0$. Not sure how to handle the case when $a\neq0$. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica tells me that after multiplying by a (horrible) power it's hypergeometric:

$
y(x)=c_1 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{3 b^2-b \sqrt{8
   a^2+b^2}}{2 b^2}} \, _1F_1\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{b^4+8 a^2 b^2}}{2
   b^2};1-\frac{\sqrt{b^4+8 a^2 b^2}}{b^2};-\frac{2}{b^2 x}\right)$
$
\quad +\quad c_2
    \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{b \sqrt{8 a^2+b^2}+3 b^2}{2
   b^2}} \, _1F_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{b^4+8 a^2 b^2}}{2
   b^2}+\frac{3}{2};\frac{\sqrt{b^4+8 a^2 b^2}}{b^2}+1;-\frac{2}{b^2
   x}\right)
$

Enjoy!

Comment: I'm sorry, after multiplying what?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit vague; I meant that you can turn into into a hypergeometric (or, rather, confluent hypergeometric because of the double pole at $x=0$) equation by writing $y=x^p u$, for some $p$, and changing variables ($z=-\frac{2}{b^2x}$). Precisely what I meant is captured in the explicit solution given.

Comment: I still don't get it, alas. If $y(x)=x^p u(x)$, then $y'=px^{p-1} u+x^p u'$, and $y''=p(p-1)x^{p-2}u+2px^{p-1}u'+x^{p}u''$. How does one choose $p$ after these are plugged in to the original equation?

Comment: It's chosen to cancel certain terms, so that it's left in the standard form- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function)- and the answer (read off from the solution) looks very much like it will come out as the solution of a quadratic equation. Bear in mind that you'll also need the change of variables (to move the irregular singular point from 0 to infinity) to get the standard form.